# Launch rspec tests with sqlite :memory: - "migrations are pending"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rspec-rails

I want to run tests using rspec on my ruby on rails app using sqlite with the memory database. However, everytime I launch rspec it tells me that migrations are pending, event if I run the migrations before hand. Is there a way to do the migrations everytime before I run the tests ?
Here's my database configuration

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  database: ":memory:"
```

Comment: How do you run your migrations for test env?

Comment: `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load schema in your tests instead of relying on migrations.

As advised in [this blogpost](https://philippe.bourgau.net/5-minutes-hack-to-speed-up-rspec-in-rails-5-using-in-memory-sqlite/#) replace

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:')
ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
load "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/schema.rb"
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
`An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: load "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/schema.rb"

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: do you have `db/schema.rb` file?